# How to add/subtract values in that are negative and positive together

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having trouble figuring out how to write the formula for my spreadsheet using multiple formulas inside the same cell. Below are actual numbers I am using and the red number in (year remaining) is what I'm trying to have as the end result. The idea behind it is that I take my (year authorized) and subtract my (year forecasted). Then as I manually enter a number into the (expended) cell, it will recalculate taking into account the difference of subtracting (expended) from (year forecasted) as to not double dip from both and added back into (year remaining). Hopefully that's elaborate enough that you get the idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

New table explaining steps to what needs to be done:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f28O1.png)

Comment: With your original example, `140882 + 8664 - 2*8400 = 132746`, but that seems awfully arbitrary. How, exactly, do you intend to arrive at the desired 132746 result?

Comment: @Dean So, to rephrase your examples (correct me if I'm wrong), you have `BUDGETED AMOUNT` and `FORECASTED AMOUNT`, and then you manually enter `ACTUAL AMOUNT SPENT`, and based on that it should calculate `AMOUNT REMAINING IN BUDGET` and/or `AMOUNT REMAINING BEFORE REACHING FORECASTED AMOUNT`...  Is this correct?

Comment: I want FORECASTED AMOUNT to be subtracted from AUTHORIZED AMOUNT....UNTIL, I enter a EXPENDED amount. Only then do I want the EXPENDED amount to be subtracted from the AMOUNT REMAINING to find the difference from which gets put back into my pot of AMOUNT REMAINING...Is that more clear?

Comment: I'd say the problem is not clear. With some figures wrong already, and saying different things in the question and comments. Can you put two situations for each example, before and after EXPENDED amount is entered, and this time, make sure the numbers are correct? Edit your question please, and all all the correct information in one single place.

Answer (score 0):

### <kbd>+</kbd> Just add the two numbers together.

```
+5 + +10 = +15
-5 + +10 = +5
+5 + -10 = -5
-5 + -10 = -15
```

In no way is `-4800 + 500 = -4200` .  Post a screen shot of the cells that contain those numbers and the formula that's giving you that answer and I can guarantee there is a third cell or number involved, with a value of 100.

---

### Edit:

After your clarification, I *think* this is what you're looking for...(?)  You start with a have a "pot" of Total `Auth Remaining` (for the Year), which is a cumulative total of :

- **Increases** each time you spend **Less** Than Forecasted on an item
- **Decreases** each time you spend **More** Than Forecasted on an
  item.

.

Am I close?

You can download an xlsx copy at [this link](http://jmp.sh/r4AIu1i).  Screenshot below:

[image: screenshot example]

Comment: To add to the confusion, OP said that he's getting `-4800 + 500 = -4200`, when he expects to get `-4800 + 500 = -4700` - neither result is correct!

Comment: @Fernando Oh you're right, I didn't catch that!  The correct answer is `-4800 + 500 = -4300`

Comment: Sorry, yes I meant -4300

Comment: @Dean ok np, could you Edit your question with that correction?  (depending on whether you meant `-4300` instead of the `-4200` or the `-4700`, each change my response in different ways.)  :-)

Comment: @Dean I *think* I know what you mean -- I updated my example above.  You can [download the xlsx](http://jmp.sh/r4AIu1i) and plug in some test numbers.  I'm curious if it's now behaving how you intended.  If so, check out the formulas I used; if not, let me know.  (The longest part is `if` statements to keeps cells blank until you enter numbers in the green cells.)

Comment: @ashleedawg I feel like you're getting somewhere. I also feel like I might be explaining this wrong or in a confusing way. Attached is a table with breakdown of the steps that need to be done within the formula. What I can't have happen is 8400 being double dipped and subtracted from the year remaining, reason why the difference needs to be figured out. Hopefully this screenshot helps out a little more. If not, I'm sorry but I'm trying. I need this entire formula in the year remaining cell (if possible). If not possible, could you tell me if an added column would be needed.